# How should I go about choosing a kernel for this function?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gaussian-process

I'm playing around with GPR and thinking about kernels.  I am looking for a kernel that could do a good job of fitting this function.

[image]

It is something I drew up just to see how well GPR can do.  Its functional form is

$$ F(x) = -x^2 + 10 + 0.3\sin(4 \pi x) + \varepsilon$$

Where $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,0.5)$.

I'm doing things in python specifically sklearn, so I have a bunch of kernels at my disposal.  So far I have tried a sum of the exponential sine wave to account for periodicity and the radial basis function.  Is there any other way to account for the quadratic part of the function?

Comment: I assume your F(x) is the generating function?  Is so (I may be wrong) why not fit it using some optimization routine?

Comment: If you are just playing around why don't you just try out some and observe what difference it makes?

Answer (score 3):

Hello have you tried the "Locally Periodic Kernels", these will work with periodic functions that slowly vary over time. You use a periodic kernel and add or multiply a local kernel, for example a RBF kernel  multiplied by a periodic kernel. This will allow one to model functions that are only locally periodic  the shape of the repeating part of the function can now change over time.

For example you can use a Periodic Kernel:

$k_{\textrm{Per}}(x, x') = \sigma^2\exp\left(-\frac{2\sin^2(\pi|x - x'|/p)}{\ell^2}\right)$.

Then multiply it by a local RBF kernel (LC):

$k_{\textrm{LocalPer}}(x, x') = k_{\textrm{Per}}(x, x')k_{\textrm{LC}}(x, x') = \sigma^2\exp\left(-\frac{2\sin^2(\pi|x - x'|/p)}{\ell^2}\right) \exp\left(-\frac{(x - x')^2}{2\ell^2}\right)$.